# How to create ansible host file on mac?

Tags: ansible, amazon-ec2

When I try to create ansible host file as follows:

```
sudo vi /usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts
```

When I try to save the file I get following error:

```
"/usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Comment: That error could be thrown if the file does not exists. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958727/where-to-store-ansible-host-file-on-mac-os-x) and [this](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html) source the path to the hosts file is different.

Comment: please post the output of `ls -lah /usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts` and also what user are you running ansible with?

Comment: @030  thanks for the response it was helpful

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
$ sudo touch /usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts
$ sudo vi /usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts
```

To create a file and then open it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the host file did not exist. So, first I created the host file at the location: /usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts
Then after that i could add the hosts to this file.